# passing variable without button onclick event

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am getting null value in  variable k can anyone help me plz ..... It is taking the input of alert but not setting value to k can I perform the same without button or click event

```
<% // some jsp code
 String key="some value";
     if(key!= null)
      {
      %>
      <html>
          <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var val = prompt("Please enter R for Read or W for Write", "");
         document.getElementById("hid").value=val;
      </script>
          </head>
          <body>
              <input type="hidden" id="hid" name="hid" />
          </body>
      </html>
      <%
      }
      String k=request.getParameter("hid");
      key=key+k;
      System.out.println(key);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just add a window.onload event handler**

```
 <% // some jsp code
     String key="some value";
         if(key!= null)
          {
          %>
          <html>
              <head>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             var val = prompt("Please enter R for Read or W for Write", "");
             window.onload = function() {document.getElementById("hid").value=val; }
          </script>
              </head>
              <body>
                  <input type="hidden" id="hid" name="hid" />
              </body>
          </html>
          <%
          }
          String k=request.getParameter("hid");
          key=key+k;
          System.out.println(key);
    %>
```

The Javascript is executing before the DOM is loaded, try either putting the code before the script (put script at base of body as recommended), or as stated use window.onload or jQuery `$(function(){});`

Comment: I tried with window.onload and putting script tag in body both r not working